# Covering space action

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

In exercise 1.3.28 in Hatcher's [Algebraic Topology](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch1.pdf), we are asked to show that for a covering space action of a group $G$ on a simply-connected space $Y$, $\pi_1(Y/G)$ is isomorphic to $G$. This is a special case of Proposition 1.40(c).

My question is: What happens if $Y$ is not locally path-connected and not simply connected? Is there a counterexample to show that Proposition 1.40(c) fails? **I am still assuming $Y$ is path-connected.**

**Edit:** I should clarify that I want to find a counterexample to proposition 1.40(c) if $Y$ is not locally path-connected, which means that I want to find a a *covering space action* of a group $G$ on a *path-connected* space $Y$ such that $G \ncong \pi_1(Y/G)/p_*(\pi_1(Y))$, where $p: Y \to Y/G$ is the quotient map. Proposition 1.40(c) implies that such a $Y$ cannot be locally path-connected, while Exercise 1.3.28 tells us that such a $Y$ cannot be simply connected.

Answer (score -2):

$S^1$ is the quotient of $R$ by $f(x)=x+1$, $Z/2$ acts on $S^1$ by the action induced by the translation $g(x)=x+1/2$ and the quotient of this action is still $S^1$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get this counterexample. What are your $Y$ and $G$ in this case?

Comment: $Y$ is $S^1$ and $G$ is $Z/2$

Comment: How can this be a counterexample though - here $Y$ is path-connected and locally path-connected so cannot serve as a counterexample to Proposition 1.40(c). I want a counterexample to the proposition, not to the exercise, if $Y$ fails to satisfy the hypothesis of being locally path-connected.